# Why my C#/ Android App does not play audio?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I'm new in developing with c#/Xamarin for android apps and I want to make a simple app that has 3 image buttons and plays 3 different sounds when clicking each button. Here's the code that I've written after trying again and again .

**The app runs in the emulator , i click the button but there is no sound.**

```
using Android.App;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Support.V7.App;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.Media;

namespace The_Useless_App_1._0
{
    [Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/AppTheme", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {

        MediaPlayer chaos_player,hallo_player,oink_player;


        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);


            void ChaosPlayer(MediaPlayer chaos_player)
            {
                chaos_player = MediaPlayer.Create(this, Resource.Raw.Chaos);
                chaos_player.Start();
                return;
            }

            void HalloPlayer (MediaPlayer hallo_player)
            {
                hallo_player = MediaPlayer.Create(this, Resource.Raw.Hallo);
                hallo_player.Start();
                return;
            }

            void OinkPlayer(MediaPlayer oink_player)
            {
                oink_player = MediaPlayer.Create(this, Resource.Raw.Oink);
                oink_player.Start();
                return;
            }

            FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.Chaos).Click += (sender, e) => ChaosPlayer(chaos_player);
            FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.Hallo).Click += (sender, e) => HalloPlayer(hallo_player);
            FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.Oink).Click  += (sender, e) =>  OinkPlayer(oink_player);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With the audio files - how have you named them and where have you put them? With android you have to not have any capital letters in the file name and they have to be in the correct folder (i believe its in the resources folder)

Comment: I ' ve stored my sound files in a folder called raw inside the resources folder. And thanks for the naming advice .. I didn't know that..

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please make sure your file put in right folder, then size of audio file should not too big, You could try to change a audio file smaller than 1M, then make a test.

I wrote a demo about Play Audio, you could refer to it.

First of all create three button(play, pause, stop).

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<Button 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/Chaos"
    android:text="Play Chaos"
/>

<Button 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/StopChaos"
    android:layout_below="@id/Chaos"
    android:text="Stop Chaos"
/>
<Button 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/PauseChaos"
    android:text="Pause Chaos"
    android:layout_below="@id/StopChaos"
/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Then, acheve the `mediaplayer`;

```
   [Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/AppTheme", MainLauncher = true)]
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    MediaPlayer chaos_player;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);


        Button Chaos = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.Chaos);
        Button StopChaos = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.StopChaos);
        Button PauseChaos = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.PauseChaos);

        //before click the button , you could instantiate MediaPlayer outside the click method;
        chaos_player = MediaPlayer.Create(this, Resource.Raw.Chaos);
        Chaos.Click += (e, o) =>
        {
            //if you click the button ,then call different method, do not instantiate MediaPlayer in here
            chaos_player.Start();

        };

        StopChaos.Click += (e, o) =>
        {
            chaos_player.Stop();

        };
        PauseChaos.Click += (e, o) =>
        {
            chaos_player.Pause();

        };

    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        base.OnStop();
        //if you stop use MediaPlayer,please release it.
        chaos_player.Release();
    }
}
```

There is a link about how to Playing Audio Files in xamarin android, you could refer to it.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AdUSSx6dsOs

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice .. my files are very small (about 1sec of audio)so thats ok .. Because of that i don't really need a stop and pause button ,but your advice is still very helpful because I've just started learning , so thank you very much..

Comment: You are welcome, I suggest you donot instantiate MediaPlayer inside the click method; You could make sure if the emluator can make a sound as well. Are there any updates for this issue? If the reply is helpful, please try to mark it as an answer,  it will help others who have similar issue.

Comment: Thank you again for commenting . Unfortunately , even if I followed your advice the problem doesn't seem to be fixed . Also sorry for being late to respond but , I had to reinstall Visual Studio because the editor didn't work at all .

Comment: After reinstall visual studio, Does this issue disappear now?

Comment: I hope so . It hasn't appeared since I reinstalled it

Comment: Can you run this code in physical machine to exclude the simulator issue?